# Найти с помощью регулярного выражения текст, где не встречалось слово

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например есть такой код

```
procedure Test1;
begin
  a := 1;
  b := 1;
end;

procedure Test2;
begin
  c := 1;
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  
end;
```

Ищу регулярным выражением

```
(procedure Test1.*?\r\n)(.*?)([ ]*?\w+?[ ]+?:=.*?\r\n)(.*?)(end;)(.+?procedure Test3;.+?begin\r\n)(.+?end;)
```

И делаю замену

```
$1$2$4$5$6$3$7
```

В цикле выполняю это несколько раз
При первом прогоне получаю

```
procedure Test1;
begin
  b := 1;
end;

procedure Test2;
begin
  c := 1;
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  a := 1;    
end;
```

При втором прогоне получаю

```
procedure Test1;
begin
end;

procedure Test2;
begin
  c := 1;
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  a := 1; 
  b := 1;
end;
```

И мне надо чтобы на этом все закончилось, но при третьем прогоне получаю

```
procedure Test1;
begin
end;

procedure Test2;
begin
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  a := 1; 
  b := 1;
  c := 1;
end;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы регулярное выражение искало до первого `end;`?

Comment: Добавить ```?``` ко всем частям между ```begin \ end``` и возможно нужно будет поуправлять ```жадностью```, но это не точно :)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2gDkwr/1

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но задача немного шире. Если быть точнее, то я переношу определенный код(определенный шаблон) автоматом из одной процедуры в другую. И надо чтобы регулярное выражение не находилось, если перед ним уже нашелся 'end;'. Но бывает так что искомый код находится ниже и регулярное выражение тоже выполняется и в этом проблема

Comment: как вариант попробовать использовать негативный просмотр вперед, вместо `.*?` использовать `(?:.(?!end;))*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не нашел легкого решения, но использовал следующий вариант.

Перед тем как выполнять замену ставлю метку(комментарий) после нужного end.
Получаю например это:

```
procedure Test1;
begin
  a := 1;
  b := 1;
end;//comment

procedure Test2;
begin
  c := 1;
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  
end;

procedure Test3;
begin
  a := 1;    
end;
```

А дальше уже использую в регулярном выражении эту метку.
В конце можно удалить эту метку опять же с помощью регулярного выражения.